# How to have a fixed interval between two columns?

Tags: html, css, html-table

We have a table as follows:

```
<table style="margin-top: 10px; float:right;">
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">SubTotal</td>
        <td align="right">${subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Tax</td>
        <td align="right">${tax}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Total</td>
        <td align="right">${total}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The third column should have a fixed interval to the second column no matter how long the value inside it is.

Can anybody give me some suggestion?

Comment: Use [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to go about it:

- using padding
- using an empty column

It boils down to whether or not it matters if the space is added in between the columns or inside one of them.

---

`padding-right` on 2nd column example:

```
td:nth-child(2) {
  padding-right: 30px;
}
```

---

`padding-left` on 3rd column example:

```
td:nth-child(3) {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

---

empty column example:

```css
td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">SubTotal</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">${subtotal}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Tax</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">${tax}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">Total</td>
        <td></td>
        <td align="right">${total}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**IMPORTANT** *(deprecation notice)*

Do NOT use `cellpadding`.
It has been [deprecated in HTML5](https://dev.w3.org/html5/pf-summary/obsolete.html#attr-table-cellpadding), along with `align`, `bgcolor`, `border`, `cellspacing`, `frame`, `rules`, `summary` and `width`.
Current browser behavior for `cellpadding` is: disregard if `padding` has been defined. Which means it will be ignored if the cell element has a defined value for `padding` *anywhere* in currently applying CSS.

It is expected to be ignored by all major browsers in the future, regardless of `padding` value.

If, for any reason, you find yourself needing an obsolete HTML feature to work, you can specify the DOCTYPE attribute accordingly. While it will make the deprecated features work, it might disable more modern features, which were not available in the HTML version you want to use.